# How do i check if a record already exists in table in springboot JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-jpa

I have a table with 4 fields. And if i inserted a record that already exists i.e all field value matches with previous record in table. How do i return record only but not insert into database ?

My model look like this:

```
@Entity
public class QuestionDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String department;
    private String year;
    private String academic_year;
    private String semester;
    private String type;
    private String subject;
    private int points;
    private int unit;

// getter, setter
```

And Controller look this:

```
@Autowired
public QuestionDetailsRepository qdRepository;

 @PostMapping("/api/questionDetails")
 public QuestionDetails addQuestion(@Valid @RequestBody QuestionDetails qDetails) {

// here i want to first check if qDetails object is already present in table . 
If present i want to return that existed record instead of inserting into table.


            QuestionDetails qd = qdRepository.save(qDetails); // save only new record
    
            return qd;
        }
```

Using postman i send data like this:

```
{
 "department" : "IT",
 "year" : "2020",
 "academic_year" : "1st year",
 "semester" : "first semester",
 "type" : "objective",
 "subject" : "JAVA",
 "points" : 10,
 "unit" : 5
}
```

Here, i am sending data that is already present in table. So, i want to check if this record already exist? If doesn't exist insert into table otherwise return that existed record.

How do i achieve that using springboot Jpa hibernate?

Comment: Can you share the data model? JPA/Hibernate does a select before insert or update. Are you sure it is inserting the data? Share some code to understand it better.

Comment: @Tushar yes, it is inserting the same data but i want to return that data instead of inserting into table for repeated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a select method in `QuestionDetailsRepository` as below. Add all the criteria which make a record unique. I am using department and year but you can use all the parameters of the `QuestionDetails` entity.

```
@Query("select qd from QuestionDetails qd where qd.department = :#{#req. department} and qd.year = :#{#req.year}")
Optional<QuestionDetails> findQuestionDetails(@Param("req") QuestionDetails req);
```

Ensure to implement the `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `QuestionDetails` class as per the unique criteria.

Your pseudo-code would look like this:

```
Optinal<QuestionDetails> optRecord = qdRepository.findQuestionDetails(qDetails);
if(opt.isPresent()){
  return opt.get();
}else{
  qdRepository.save(qDetails);
}
```

Comment: I have generated the equals() and hashcode() for department and year but i am getting error "query didn't return unique result :2 ".

Comment: You have more than one record for the criteria. What is the unique criteria on the table? Did you add all parameters from request other than department and year?

Comment: The unique criteria on the table is if any column have different value than the other records. Yes, i did add all parameters from request but i get the same error. So, next time i add only department and year only but still getting samer error.

Comment: Can you run the query manually and share the results? You may need to change the return type to list or remove duplicate entries. It seems a unique constraint is missing at DB level. Another option is to change the return type to List.

Comment: It worked after changing return type. Thanks for your time. Really appreciated.